# How to implement MultiUnitValue class using C++ TMP

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I wrote this class in VC++, that is obviously non standard compliant (TBH seems weird that it isn't allowed by the standard)

1. How can I convert it to standard C++11?

Code:

```cpp
#include <functional>
template <typename T, typename U, typename T_to_U >
class MultiUnitValue  //Multi for now == 2 :)
{
    const T t;
    T_to_U conversion_function;
public:
    MultiUnitValue()    : t(0)
    {}
    MultiUnitValue(T t_): t(t_)
    {}
    template<typename V>
    V in() const
    {
        BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(0);
        // "you are trying to call in with type(unit) not supported"
    }
    template<>
    T in<T>() const
    {
        return t;
    }
    template<>
    U in<U>() const
    {
        return conversion_function(t);
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
auto f = [](int i){return i*2.54;};

MultiUnitValue<int, float,decltype(f)> muv(10);
auto rv = muv.in<float>();
```

2. I put BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT to prevent incorrect usage,
   but it looks like MSVC doesn't instantiate it if not used(like I expect), but while trying to port it to g++4.7 it was firing even when the template wasn't instantiated? 
   Replacing it with static_assert doesn't work...

Any way to work around this?

Comment: Are you interesting in solution with variadic templates? I am asking, because VC++ still does not support this one of the nicest thing in C++11.

Comment: I care about learning C++11 for the long term... in a sense that I care about learning C++11 and not worrying about how to hack around noncompliant compiler. BTW lets hope we will get VT in VS 2012 SP. :D

Comment: I added version with variadic templates as the main solution in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution was not "standard compliant", because member functions cannot be specialized in class template. This is because of general rule that functions cannot be partially specialized - so even "full" specialization of member function template is actually partial specialization because of not fully specialized class.

---

My solutions:

### C++11 version

Your example with my version, I believe this is what you want:

```
int main(){
  auto f1 = [](int i){return i*2.54;};
  auto f2 = [](int i){ std::stringstream ss; ss << i; return ss.str(); };
  MultiUnitValue<int, float, std::string>  vv(1, f1, f2);
  std::cout << vv.in<int>() << "\n";
  std::cout << vv.in<float>() << "\n";
  std::cout << vv.in<std::string>() << "\n";
  // std::cout << vv.in<long>() << "\n"; // error to compile
}
```

First of all - you need the special conversion base classes, for a single conversion, you will see in next code fragment that calling conversion via base class function causes that "non specified" conversion, like this for `long` will not compile.

```
template <class T, class U>
class Conversion {
public:
    Conversion(const std::function<U(const T&)>& f) : f(f) {}
    U convert (const T& v) const { return f(v); }
private:
   std::function<U(const T&)>  f;
};
template <class T>
class Conversion<T,T> {
public:
    T convert (const T& v) const { return v; }
};
```

And your class with using variadic templates:

```
template <class T, class... V> // V... means all desired conversions
class MultiUnitValue : private Conversion<T,T>, private Conversion<T,V>... {
// allowed conversion:         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
public:
   MultiUnitValue(T v, const std::function<V(const T&)>&... f) : Conversion<T,V>(f)..., v(v) {}

   template <class U>
   U in() const
   {
      // this static assert is not needed - but just to show the message
      static_assert(std::is_base_of<Conversion<T,U>, MultiUnitValue<T,V...>>::value, 
                   "Not allowed conversion");

      // static_assert is not needed 
      // since if you MultiUnitValue does not derive from Conversion<T,U> 
      // - then this call will not compile too
      return this->Conversion<T,U>::convert(v);
   }

private:
   T v;
};
```

LVS example: http://liveworkspace.org/code/05b6ada146cc8f05d027a5536859a087

### Version without variadic templates:

I also prepared solution without variadic templates, since VC++ still does not support them.

Second: the conversion and coversion limitation should be now in your T_to_U type.

With this approach usage will slightly inconvenient in the comparison to C++11 version:

```
int main(){
  auto f1 = [](int i){return i*2.54;};
  auto f2 = [](int i){ std::stringstream ss; ss << i; return ss.str(); };
  // next 2 lines differ from C++11 version
  typedef ConvertFunctions2<int, float, std::string> CF_f1_f2; 
  MultiUnitValue<int, CF_f1_f2>  vv(1, CF_f1_f2(f1, f2));
  std::cout << vv.in<int>() << "\n";
  std::cout << vv.in<float>() << "\n";
  std::cout << vv.in<std::string>() << "\n";
  // std::cout << vv.in<long>() << "\n"; // error to compile
}
```

The `MultiUnitValue` will be simpler than in your example, simpler even from my C++11 version, but the `class CF` will be much more complicated:

```
template <class T, class CF>
class MultiUnitValue {
public:
   MultiUnitValue(T v, const CF& cf) : v(v), cf(cf) {}

   template <class U>
   U in() const
   {
      return cf.Conversion<T,U>::convert(v);
   }

private:
   T v;
   CF cf;
};
```

The simple "helper" conversion classes will be identical as in C++11 version:

```
template <class T, class U>
class Conversion {
   ...
};
template <class T>
class Conversion<T,T> {
   ...
};
```

And the variadic template alternative in VC++ (and in old days of C++03):

```
template <class T>
class ConvertFunctions0 : public Conversion<T,T> {};

template <class T, class V1>
class ConvertFunctions1 : public Conversion<T,T>, public Conversion<T,V1> {
public:
  ConvertFunctions1(std::function<V1(const T&)> f1) : Conversion<T,V1>(f1) {}
};

template <class T, class V1, class V2>
class ConvertFunctions2 : public Conversion<T,T>, public Conversion<T,V1>, public Conversion<T,V2> {
public:
  ConvertFunctions2(std::function<V1(const T&)> f1, std::function<V2(const T&)> f2) 
  : Conversion<T,V1>(f1), Conversion<T,V2>(f2) 
  {}
};
```

As you can see - adding `ConvertFunctions3`, `ConvertFunctions4` is not so big trouble...

Full example at [ideone](http://ideone.com/qhsDSR)

Comment: MS just announced CTP of VS2012 compiler with VT support. :)

Comment: I believe the pressure from developers were big enough:D C++11 is really big improvement, VS has its own additions to C++, but they just cannot ignore C++11... BTW, thanks for accepting.

Answer (score 1):

The first issue is that you can't specialize member function templates within a class, and you can't specialize them outside a (template) class because then they'd be partial function specializations.  The easiest way to work around this is to use private member function overloads:

```
private:
    T in(T *) const { return t; }
    U in(U *) const { return conversion_function(t); }
    template<typename V> V in(V *) const {
        static_assert((V *)0, "you are trying to call in with type(unit) not supported");
    }
public:
    template<typename V> V in() const { return in((V *)0); }
```

This also demonstrates how to fix the issue with the `static_assert` always firing; you need to make its assertion expression dependent on a template parameter.

The next issue is that your template won't instantiate with a lambda type template parameter, because lambdas (even captureless lambdas) are not default-constructible.  You can fix this by either going back to a traditional functor (`struct` with `operator()`) or convert the lambda type to a default-constructible type that calls the lambda.

One strategy is to indirect a void pointer when calling, since captureless lambdas shouldn't care what their `this` pointer is:

```
template<typename L> struct default_constructible_lambda {
  template<typename... Args> auto operator()(Args &&...args) const
    -> decltype(std::declval<L>()(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
      return (*(L *)(0))(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
};
MultiUnitValue<int, float, default_constructible_lambda<decltype(f)>> muv(10);
```

This is still undefined behaviour, though; it's consistent with the standard for the lambda's function pointer to be stored within the closure type, in which case this would result in calling through a void pointer.

Comment: if you can try my code in VS 2010, auto rv = muv.in<float>(); returns expected result.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl I'm sure it does; it's still non-conformant code, though.

Comment: I just tested it in VS 2012 RC, it works... maybe Herb could slip this into standard. :P